# How to push a table view controller from a regular view controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I have a view controller with a button. When the user clicks the button, I want the user to be navigated to a table view controller (i.e. be shown a table view).

When button is clicked, i have it call the following method:

```
- (void)loadTableViewController{

    TableViewViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The above code seems to be fine since in debug mode after the last line, I am taken to the TableView Controller's implementation file. Here is where things break down... 
I declared `tableView` as a property of the `tableViewController`

Here is the code for the viewDidLoad method:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

The program breaks down after the last line in Debug mode. Not sure at all what is wrong... the only other changes I have made are to return 1 section and 1 row for the table. Here is that code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: adding error details.

The error I get is looks like a generic "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Please keep in mind that I am very new to Xcode and programming in general. So I may not be looking at the right place to find the specific error.

Comment: you need more detail than "breaks down". what errors do you get, what behaviour that you didn't expect?

Comment: Yes some error messages would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `UITableViewController's` initialisation method. Instead, use

```
TableViewViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
```

After that, initialising your table view inside your `UITableViewController` class is pointless, because `UITableViewController` is already doing that for you (that's the point of using it) and instead, access the `tableView` property with `self.tableView`.

Also note that `- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` is only available for iOS 6.0 and above (will crash below that)

And for populating the cell just use :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", indexPath.row + 1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: so, if i understand correctly, in the method that is called when the button is clicked, I change the initialization to the one you provided. In addition, I no longer need the initialization in the viewDidLoad method of the TableViewController. Is that right? So all i have in that method is `[super viewDidLoad];`

Comment: I tried that, now the app crashes in the cell creator method. the line `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` seems to have an error. the error is "terminating with uncaught exception"

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if you have anymore problems.

Comment: awesome! thanks a million. Can't give you vote up because i lack reputation, but do you mind explaining what was wrong with the cell creator?

Comment: my pleasure. Good luck with what comes next ! :)

Comment: Oh i see. i never allocated/initialized the cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the problem is caused by this line:

```
TableViewViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
```

You are missing the actual nib name. Replace nil with your nib name.